# Liferay 7 - Live Log Viewer

Tags: logging, liferay

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Background:** I've deployed the Live Log Viewer from the [liferay-marketplace](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/88455776). This works on the Liferay instance hosted on a Windows system. However this doesn't work on the Liferay instance hosted on a Linux system.

**Issue:**
The browser shows the error in the console,

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<domain-name>/o/ka' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

and the server logs have the error,

```
ERROR [ajp-nio-8009-exec-2][UploadServletRequestFilter:61] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol
```

How do I resolve this issue to track live logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have created Live Logs plugin.

You must have Apache in front.

Do the following
Use Apache module mod_proxy_wstunnel:

```
sudo a2enmod mod_proxy_wstunnel
```

Then use it to let WebSocket connections through by adding this to apache.conf:

```
ProxyPass "/ws2/"  "ws://localhost:<your_port>/ws"
```

And make sure you have enabled an HTTP connector in Tomcat by using 
`<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port=<your_port> ...>` in server.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using Apache 2.2, which doesn't support websockets. I'll upgrade to 2.4 and respond back with results.